# url changing anchor links in polymer

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

I have 2 Polymer pages sharing one navigation menu structure. Only one menu item links to page two, the others are linking to id's on page one. How would I write the menu links from page two to id's on page one with JavaScript?

(Hashtags in a links are not relative to URLs in custom Polymer elements, and neither same page anchor links like `<a href="#p1">p1</a>` nor url changing links like `<a href="example.com/nextpage.htm#p1"></a>` work therefore.)

This seems to be a general problem with custom elements, and there is not much documentation on how to fix this in the Polymer-project page, therefore.

I have got help with same page id linking, but unfortunately am still really struggling with JavaScript, and have no idea how I would go about referencing a target element on a previous page by DOM methods, and attaching the necessary event-listeners and scroll functions.

This [JS Bin from Frankie Fu](http://therapie-jetzt.de/Aktuelles.html) is showing how to do this with same page links, but I would need to do it with url changing links.

My pages are therapie-jetzt.de/index.html and [therapie-jetzt.de/Aktuelles.html](http://therapie-jetzt.de/index.html) (page two). The menu items are all linking to id's on page one, except for "Aktuelles", which points to page two. So what I need to do is point all other menu items in the menu on Aktuelles.html to the corresponding paragraph id's in the first page, index.html.

I guess I would have to start with getting and storing the previous page, say with document.referrer, put it in a variable, and query my id's, and then go on from that? But that wouldn't work, as I can only query nodes in the current dom/window object, right?

The easiest way would probably be to not load a second page at all and just hide the other content away when the menu item Aktuelles is tapped...

Lex

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. When I edited your /index.html page to link to /Aktuelles.html##Arbeitsrecht-Newsdghgi51q35kee4gmvp8see17hs then clicking that link took me to the Aktuelles page and scrolled to the appropriate place on the screen. Can you edit your question for clarity a bit? Specifically I would recommend answering the following questions: What behavior would you like to achieve? What have you tried? What happened when you tried it? How was the result you got different from what you wanted? It's a bit tedious and potentially repetitive I know, but it helps folks answer you better!

Comment: Sorry for making a simple question incomprehensible. The /Aktuelles.html only has a Feedburner feed, so the link to this page is just going to the top, which is fine. I want to link back from the /Aktuelles.html page with the menu links, and specifically to the id sections on the first page (the index.html). I'll bring the unvulcanized pages back, so you can see it better.

Comment: related with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689640/create-anchor-element-in-polymer